# playing two videos simultaneously

Tags: windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I need to play cyclically two videos (each is 15 seconds length) simultaneously in my app. And time by time I need to change opacity of one video (in DoubleAnimation), to let it appear above another video. Playing two videos need for syncronization purposes.

I tried to use MediaElements to play video, but I can not get them to play the video simultaneously. I think it's impossible. Am I right?

Also I tried to divide my videos into 450 frames (30 frames per second) and use ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames, (example: http://compiledexperience.com/windows-phone/tutorials/candle), but this way uses too many memory (used memory is about 250 MB, though the maximum usage must be 90 MB).

At last I tried to use DispatcherTimer and in it's Tick procedure change the Source Properties of two Images, but it works slow enough.

Help me please, is there any way to do this without lags?

Comment: Not an answer, but the reason it's not working is because you can only use one `MediaElement`on a page. If possible, you could just create one video which contains all the animations and effects and just use that video on loop.

Comment: I need to let video appear/disappear by user's choice. So, I want to create likeness of morphing effect, when one video gradually turning into another. But moment of start this effect is defined by user (for example tap event).

Comment: also not an answer, but just a suggestion ... or a thought really, why couldn't you use a set of temp files for a stream/cue video file wherein you would calculate the exact frames which will be "spliced" and render them into separate "splice" files. Then you play vid_1part_1, splice_1, vid2part_1, splice_2, vid_1part_2, splice_3, vid_2part_2, splice_4 ... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be try using **CompositionTarget.Rendering**
as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838.aspx

The problem you may run into is that the time between calls is not guaranteed and so you may get frames running faster or slower.

However Charles Petzold has a post showing how to determine the time elapsed in a manner that would allow you to pick the correct frame to display whenever the Rendering event happens. The example code should be helpful:
http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2010/06/CompositionTarget-Rendering-and-RenderEventArgs.html