# Is there a way to improve Image memory usage for Image controls using the same images?

Tags: performance, image, windows-phone-7, optimization, sprite-sheet

In a WP7 game I'm building my `Enemy` classes are wrapped in an `EnemyControl`.
The Enemy Control uses a `spritesheet` of all the different animation states for that enemy type. There are only 4 images which I statically cache the bitmaps for.

The problem I have is that despite both the image being cached (`BitmapImage` statically and `CacheMode="BitmapCache"`), when the Image is loaded by the control it adds approximately 2 meg of Texture/System memory per control.

This is a significant problem as it limits the number of enemies I can conceivably have on screen.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could improve this situation? or otherwise solve it?

Here's the xaml if interested:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canEnemyControl">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="enemyControlTransform" X="0"/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <Canvas.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry x:Name="clipGeometry" Rect="0,0,60,60" />
    </Canvas.Clip>
    <Image x:Name="imgEnemy" Stretch="None" CacheMode="BitmapCache" >
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="enemyImageTransform" X="0" Y="0" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: 2MB seems a lot for a 60x60 image. Are you scaling the image down?

Comment: The images are in the scale of 1501 x 300. ~100k on disk. The clipping technique limits that to 60x60 shown at a time.

Comment: The reason for the single image is due to some crazinesses I couldn't solve with storyboard and control resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your implementation will scale because I don't think the multiple `Image` elements know to share the same bitmap cache.

### Solution: CompositionTarget.Rendering and WriteableBitmapEx

One possible solution would be to use [CompositionTarget.Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838.aspx) for rendering like in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073433/playing-two-videos-simultaneously/10125496#10125496). This fires an event before the screen is updated so you can do your own drawing. I believe this is how Krashlander and some other Silverlight games work (though I think he may have switched over to XNA in later versions).

Then I think that you can use [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) to use one instance of your source image to draw it into multiple places on a buffer. You should scale much better because you have your buffer the size of your screen/viewport, and you have your one copy of each image. The memory requirements for displaying 1 enemy and 1000 should be the same.

---

I will add a disclaimer that I haven't tried this exact approach, but I do use `CompositionTarget.Rendering` in one of my apps for smooth screen updates.

Comment: WriteableBitmapEx is exactly the route I followed, it massively improved things, but not enough to stop memory issues on a 256Mb emulator. Works a treat on the 512 and device though.

Comment: Glad to hear you're making progress. If you are using WriteableBitmapEx to draw the scene you should probably turn off bitmap caching. Or are you setting the Image controls to the small image you got out of WriteableBitmapEx?

Comment: Exactly that, I statically cut up the animation frame sets (walk, attack, die) into WriteableBitmaps using the WireableBitmapEx crop method in the SplashScreen. Swapping out the image source from one cached WriteableBitmap seems to be much quicker than swapping cached BitmapImages. I'd love it if there was a way to further optimise that.

Comment: Marking as answer as this is what I'd gone for and there haven't been any other suggestions.